# How to make a Font Family Fallback in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

It would be great if Flutter allow us to specify our own font fallback chain, just like what we can do now in CSS's font-family property, because browsers support different fonts. Is there a way to do so in flutter?

*for example Raleway as first option, open sans as second option and sans-serif as default

Comment: What's the need? Why do you need?

Comment: I need it for flutter web. Not every browser supports Raleway, so it would be nice to have a custom font fallback.

Answer (score 2):

I found a property in textstyles ,,fontFamilyFallback'' which does the job ^–^